# Using recursion to convert list members into an integer value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot get listA as integer 2345 with this recursion function. I want to convert [2,3,4,5] to 2345.

```
listA = [2,3,4,5]
n = len(listA)

def fun(n):       
    if(n == 0):
        return listA[n]
    else:
        return fun((listA[n]) + (10**n))
        
fun(listA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `len()` and powers of 10:

```
def conv(lst):
    return 10*conv(lst[:-1]) + lst[-1] if lst else 0

print(conv([2,3,4,5])) # 2345
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but you have some issues.

1. You aren't going through the list but rather running the recursion on the "n-th" element of the list (which isn't even a valid index).
2. You have no "quit" condition.
3. You aren't concatenating the list together, but concatenating the length of the list together.

You will find that the following code solves these issues.

```
    def fun(listA):

        n = len(listA)

        if n == 0:
            return
        elif n == 1:
            return listA[0]
        else:
            return int(str(listA[0]) + str(fun(listA[1:])))

    listA = [2,3,4,5]
    fun(listA)
```

If you aren't comfortable with type-casting, you can change the final return statement:

```
return (10**(n-1))*listA[0] + fun(listA[1:])
```

Comment: "You have no "quit" condition." This is more commonly referred to as a base case.

Comment: Can we do it without type casting?

Comment: @YarrakVar I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to get the length of the list beforehand. Instead you can get the length as you go.

```
l1 = [2,3,4,5]
def fun(l):
    if l1:
        return l1.pop(0)*(10**len(l1)) + fun(l)
    return 0
print(fun(l1))
```

Output:

```
2345
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
listA = [2,3,4,5]


def turnLstToInt(lst):
    return turnLstToIntHelper(lst,0)

def turnLstToIntHelper(lst,index):
    if index>len(lst)-1: # if greater than list return 0
        return 0
    power = len(lst)-1-index # find 10's power of digit
    placeVal = lst[index]*(10**power) # get value of digit at power level
    return placeVal + turnLstToIntHelper(lst,index+1)


print(turnLstToInt(listA))
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this question is requesting recursion, but an interesting (and probably much faster) solution is the following:

```py
def fun(lst):
    return sum([n*10**i for i, n in enumerate(lst[::-1])])
```

#### Test

```py
>>> fun([1,2,3,4])
1234

>>> fun([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1])
1000010001

>>> fun([0,0,0,5])
5

>>> fun([9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0] * 10)
9876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210

>>> len(str(fun([9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0] * 10)))
100
```

#### Explanation

Assume `lst = [2, 3, 4, 5]`.

```py
def fun(lst):
    return sum(
        [
            n*10**i for i, n in 
            enumerate(
                lst[::-1]
            )
        ]
    )
```

- `lst[::-1]` takes a list of number and reverses it, e.g. `[2, 3, 4, 5]` → `[5, 4, 3, 2]`. This is needed because of the later logic.
- `enumerate()` takes a list of items, and returns a generator (essentially just a list) of tuples, the same length as the input list, each tuple containing two items: the index of the item in the list, and the item itself, e.g. `[5, 4, 3, 2]` → `[[(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2)]]`.
- `n*10**i for i, n` this list comprehension is a cool bit of code. It takes the list of index/item pairs returned by `enumerate`, and multiples the number by 10 raised to the power of `index`, e.g. `[(0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2)]]` → `[5*1, 4*10, 3*100, 2*1000]` → `[5, 40, 300, 2000]`
- `sum` adds the resulting numbers together, e.g.

  ```
  5 + 40 + 300 + 2000  =  2000 + 300 + 40 + 5

  2000 +
  300 +
    40 +
     5 =
  2345
  ```

That's it!